# mysql really simple queries took long time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, mysql-5.6

I give you samples from slow-query-log.

mysql version:5.6.14,
8gb server 6gb free memory,
innodb tables

for example: id is primary key when I type this query in phpmyadmin is very fast but its still in my slow query log

```
# Query_time: 3.226675  Lock_time: 0.000046 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1385980918;
update `rsslists` set `lastTimeRead` = '1385980913', `total` = '66502', `quality` =      '0.028284863613124' where `id` = '146';
```

or this query:

```
 # Query_time: 2.284815  Lock_time: 0.000047 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
 SET timestamp=1385980935;
 select * from `articles` where `guid` = '1.2180130' limit 1;
```

explain: 
[image: explain]

'guid' is index
really simple queries I have no ideas why they taking so long time sometimes

Comment: Try running an explain on the query.

Comment: i update my question with image

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below key points to optimize the query.

1. Optimize Your Queries For the Query Cache
2. EXPLAIN Your SELECT Queries
3. LIMIT 1 When Getting a Unique Row
4. Index the Search Fields
5. Index and Use Same Column Types for Joins
6. Do Not ORDER BY RAND()
7. Avoid SELECT *
8. Almost Always Have an id Field
9. Use ENUM over VARCHAR
10. Get Suggestions with PROCEDURE ANALYSE()
11. Use NOT NULL If You Can
12. Prepared Statements
13. Unbuffered Queries
14. Store IP Addresses as UNSIGNED INT
15. Fixed-length (Static) Tables are Faster
16. Vertical Partitioning
17. Split the Big DELETE or INSERT Queries
18. Smaller Columns Are Faster
19. Choose the Right Storage Engine
20. Use an Object Relational Mapper
21. Be Careful with Persistent Connections

For more details , Refer [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/)

Comment: i know that points as i said i am following them not helping me.. tnx

Comment: Are you using Table level locking? If so, it will lock the table until particular process complete. during this period, if you run even simple query, it'll take time. Simply to say, r u using table partition?

Answer (score 0):

If these tables are huge and have multiple indexes, the insert can be quite slow.
You should log all your queries and see how other inserts perform.

As for the select, there should be an index on guid, otherwise it will be slow if it is a large table.

Comment: as i said i have index on guid.. still slow :/ tnx

Comment: If I see the 'explain' I doubt it has anything to do with your queries or your tables. Please run your query again in a database tool like HeidiSQL and check if it REALLY takes 3 seconds or if these where incidents.

Comment: when i run it on phpmyadmin she very fast. the problem is that i can see in my log-queries-log that sometimes she run in 3 sec

Comment: If the behaviour is this inconsistent it's very likely some problem with the database server, not the dbms. Maybe you're memory bound? How often do the slow queries occur? Is it really a problem?